# What is wrong in my While loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am pretty new to Java and still practicing. I did a simple exercise with user-defined methods. The code is in below. When I run the code,it seems like the if statement(in whileloop) is not working. The code ignores the if-statement and directly loop back. for example output like this(no place to input var response):
Enter item name: 
milk
Enter price for milk:
1
Enter the quantity for this item: 
2
More items? (y/n)
Enter item name:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TotalPrice {
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double total = getTotal();
    print(total);
}
public static double getTotal()
{
    double total = 0;
    Boolean moreItems = true;
    String response;
    while(moreItems)
    {
        total += getItemPrice(getItemName());
        System.out.println("More items? (y/n)");
        response = in.nextLine();
        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        { moreItems = false;}


    }
    return total;
}
public static String getItemName()
{
    String name;
    System.out.println("Enter item name: ");
    name = in.nextLine();
    return name;
}
public static double getItemPrice(String value)
{
    double price = 0;
    try{
        System.out.println("Enter price for " + value + ":");
        price = in.nextDouble();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid data type entered.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int quantity = getItemQuantity();
    return quantity * price;
}

public static int getItemQuantity()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity for this item: ");
    int quantity = in.nextInt();
    return quantity;
}
public static void print(double total)
{
    System.out.printf("The total for your grocery items is: $%5.2f, "
            + "thanks for shopping with us!\n\n", total);

}
```

}

Comment: In what way does it act contrary to your expectations?

Comment: The code should show "More items? (y/n)", then I input y or n then if-statement. But now it show "More items (y/n)" and "Enter item name:" together. "response = in.nextLine();" seems like ignored.